# While true fetching inputs from list in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I'm looking for an alternative with while loop that should retrieve the inputs from one file. Even I failed to interpret this with while true condition, in this case I'm unable to give the variables from a file like (`cat filename`),

My requirement is to check 100 servers whether they are up or not via a ping test for every 5 minutes and log it some custom location (let's say `` /tmp/output/out-`date +%F` ``). And also the same script should delete the same logs after 7 days and max size not exceed 1MB per file size.

```
while read IP
do
ping -c1 $IP &> /dev/null && echo $IP is up  || echo $IP is down
sleep 2
done < IP
```

Note: to run this script in infinite loop, I'm unable to parse the input as variable from file.

```
while true
do 
...
done < filename
```

Ideas appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use a cron job to schedule the check every 5 minutes and logrotate to manage the log files. I also don't quite understand your actual problem: you're unable to read the input from a file *because* of the infinite loop?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Even if the op needs a cron for this, they needs a working script for this, or probably two. One for checking if  a server is up and the another for log rotation.

Comment: @sjsam I agree - I mentioned it because I think they want to to all in this script. Or not. It's not clear to me.

Comment: Check `logrotate` :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tasks run in parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

t=5m                             # time interval
p=()                             # pid list

_pingAndLog(){                   # $1 is the server ip list
  local ip
  while :; do
    while read -r ip || [[ -n $ip ]]; do
      if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "`date +%H:%M`: $ip is up"
      else
        echo "`date +%H:%M`: $ip is down"
      fi >>pingtest-`date +%F`.log
    done <"$1"                   # $1 = ip list
    sleep "$t"
  done
}

_killOldLog(){
  while :; do
    # use "-mtime +7" to find old files, 7 days
    find . -type f -mtime +7 -name 'pingtest-*\.log' -delete
    sleep 24h
  done
}

_cleanUp(){
  echo kill ${p[@]}
  kill ${p[@]}
}

for s in *\.list; do             # for each file ip list
  [[ "$s" = '*.list' ]] && break # no file found, then quit
  _pingAndLog "$s" & p+=($!)     # run in background, remember pid
done
_killOldLog & p+=($!)

trap _cleanUp 0 2 3              # 0-exit; 2-interrupt, 3-quit

wait                             # wait backround jobs; Ctrl-C to exit
```

---

**Note:**

1. Because logfiles are separated by date, so maybe no need to check their sizes; just delete those that are old.
2. `while sleep "$t"; do .. done` is also OK to contruct an endless loop as you required.
3. I've modify this script so that it can ping in parallel, multiple list of IPs.

Comment: Thanks that got worked :) still the excecution takes more time . Can we enable multiple threads in this script ? preferrably more than 10 . Does enabling threads can acheive by parallel binary ?

Comment: To ping in parallel? I think you can split the server list into some smaller lists, and each list has it's own pinging task --example: 4 lists, each has 25 servers, pinging concurrently-- so you've got parallel pinging. But I believe that's not needed at all. It's just pinging some servers, not doing some what that really need parallel.